# bulk insert rowterminator issue flat file uses | as row and field terminator

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, bulkinsert

So my problem is I am not entirely sure what I should use as my row termintor. I used used |, \r\n, 0x0a. But nothing seems to be working. I am importing a dataset that I didn't create but it has this set up

column1row1|column2row1|column3row1|column1row2|column2row2|column3row2|

So the data is using a pipe as both the row and field terminator. I just don't have a clue as to how to fix it.

```
Delete from Nations 
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.TempImport
(
id varchar(50),
ruler varchar(50),
name varchar(50),
alliance varchar(50),
alliance_id varchar(50),
alliance_date varchar(50),
alliance_status varchar(50),
govt_type varchar(50),
religion varchar(50),
team varchar(50),
created varchar(50),
tech varchar(50),
infra varchar(50),
land varchar(50),
war_status varchar(50),
resource1 varchar(50),
resource2 varchar(50),
ns varchar(50),
defcon varchar(50),
soliders varchar(50),
tanks varchar(50),
cruise varchar(50),
nuke varchar(50)
)
GO
BULK INSERT dbo.TempImport FROM 'C:\VEDataImport\CyberNations_SE_Nation_Stats\CyberNations_SE_Nation_Stats.txt' WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = '|', ROWTERMINATOR = '\r\n', FIRSTROW=2)
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.nations
(
id,
ruler,
name,
alliance,
alliance_id,
alliance_date,
alliance_status,
govt_type,
religion,
team,
created,
tech,
infra,
land,
war_status,
resource1,
resource2,
ns,
defcon,
soliders,
tanks,
cruise,
nuke
)
SELECT  id,
ruler,
name,
alliance,
alliance_id,
alliance_date,
alliance_status,
govt_type,
religion,
team,
created,
tech,
infra,
land,
war_status,
resource1,
resource2,
ns,
defcon,
soliders,
tanks,
cruise,
nuke
FROM       dbo.TempImport
where alliance_id ='10010'
GO
DROP TABLE dbo.TempImport
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.nations
(link
)
SELECT 'http://www.cybernations.net/nation_drill_display.asp?Nation_ID='+id
from dbo.nations
```

Comment: Could you import the whole file as a single nvarchar(max) string, replace every N pipes with char(10) + char(13), and then export it as a proper flat file?

Comment: Try using `ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'`

Comment: \n worked perfectly and then I just had to do susbtring(field,1,len(field)-1) to get rid of the last |